# Dart library layout

Tags: dart

I'm struggling with Dart library layout.
I tried the following

```
lib/
  A.dart
  B.dart
  my_lib.dart
```

where:
A.dart

```
class A {
  B myB;   
}
```

B.dart

```
class A {
  B myB;   
}
```

my_lib.dart

```
#library('my_lib');
#source('A.dart');
#source('B.dart');
```

But in A.dart, in Dart Editor there is a problem: B - no such type.
If I import B.dart in that file, via

```
#import('B.dart)',
```

but now it claims that part of library can only contain part directive.
According to http://news.dartlang.org/2012/07/draft-spec-changes-to-library-and.html

```
partDirective:
  metadata part  stringLiteral “;”
;
```

But that doesn't work for me either.
What am I missing?

Comment: Having similar problem, however chosen answer did not fix :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the latest SDK and try:

*a.dart*

```
class A {
  B myB;
}
```

*b.dart*

```
class B {

}
```

*lib.dart*

```
library mylib;

part 'a.dart';
part 'b.dart';
```

That should work.

Comment: I used Dart SDK version 13075, and it seems to work. Strangely, when the editor gets confused when the file names are uppercase, but when I change everything from upper to lowecase and go back, it is happy again.

Comment: @Lesiak Use lowercase filenames and underscores for spaces; that is what the Dart style guide tells you to do.

Answer (score 4):

Due to new release changes the layout has to look like the followed example:

*a.dart*

```
part of mylib;

class A {
  B myB;
}
```

*b.dart*

```
part of mylib;

class B {

}
```

*lib.dart*

```
library mylib;

part 'a.dart';
part 'b.dart';
```